# In the function of createTimeSeriesAggregator of DolphinDB, what's the relationship between window size and steps?

Tags: database, stream, time-series, dolphindb

In the function of createTimeSeriesAggregator of DolphinDB, what's the relationship between window size and parameter `step`? When is the first execution get triggered with or without using parameter "useWindowStartTime"?